# Remove %20 from URL using jquery

Tags: jquery

When i am trying to get query string value from URL using JQuery, It replace space to %20 for each 1 space.If there are 3space then my query string value contain %20 3times.

i want to replace these %20 back with space using Jquery, so that i can use these query string value.
How can i do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JavaScript has [`encodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) functions.